# How create similar widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I want to create a similar widget, but I don't know how to do it.

[image: How the widget should look like]

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: you mean this => https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for a [slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html), one of Flutters standard controls.

You can change it's appearance to match your example more closely as covered by the linked documentation.